# BizTalk Mapping Fields to a Sequence

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-mapper

I am getting my hands on BizTalk and VS. My input schema looks something similar to this.

```
<root>
  <order>
    <orderid>
    <orderdate>
    ...
    ...
```

and the output schema

```
<order>
  <header:sequence>
    <element name="orderid">
    <element name="orderdate">
    ...
    ...
  </header:sequence>
```

In short, in output, the header is a sequence of complex types and individual nodes in the source are enumerated as the sequence in the output.

How do we solve this in Visual Studio?

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is having a looping functoid that goes from each of the element being mapped and to the repeating destination element.  And then two links from the source elements the first that is a standard link `Copy text value`, the second that goes to the name attribute, for which you change the link to `Copy name`.

[image]

Input

```
<root>
    <order>
        <orderid>1234567890</orderid>
        <orderdate>2020-01-28</orderdate>
    </order>
</root>
```

Output

```
<order>
    <header>
        <element name="orderid">1234567890</element>
        <element name="orderdate">2020-01-28</element>
    </header>
</order>
```

Note: You can change the order of what is output by using the reorder inputs in the Configure Looping Functoid.